# Get list of missing documents from MongodDB

Tags: python, mongodb

First mongodb project so it's probably obvious but my google fu is insufficient or I'm approaching it wrong.

I have a collection in mongodb.  Each document has an `id` field that is unique.  In my program I end up with a list of these ids and I want to make a slow expensive call to an api if I don't have a copy of the corresponding document in mongodb.

Obviously, I don't want to make the expensive call if I don't have to so the solution seems to be I need to retrieve the full list and compare:

```
ids = [45, 23, 45, 88, 34, 28] # Except many more
items = db.items.find({'id': {'$in': ids}}, {'id':1})
missingIds = compareFx(ids, items)
for missingId in missingIds:
     doc = expensiveCall(missingId)
     db.items.insert_one(doc)
```

That requires me to do a full retrieve of all existing/matching documents when I'm just looking for the ones that don't exist.  There is an `$exists` operator but it seems to only operate on fields not documents, but maybe I just don't see how to use it.

Is there some sort of operator/combination of operators to get back the ids that weren't found or is this the right/best way to do this?

Comment: What are the `compareFx` and your so called `expensiveCall` function doing?

Comment: There is no better way to find missing documents, from ids list.

Comment: `expensiveCall` is a call to a rate limited external API that's not under my control and `compareFx` is essentially `list(set(ids) - set([x['id'] for x in items]))`, but I don't think their content should impact the situation.